# modify result of an if in a foreach loop in an attempted result PowerShell

Tags: powershell, loops, if-statement, boolean

I've made an if statement like this

```
$fin = $list.UF6E8_CANAL -match "ML"
if ($list.UF6E8_CANAL -match "ML"){1}
else {0}
```

Which works as it is, but as soon as I call it like

```
write-output "<Index Nom=`"ALERTE_MAIL`" Valeur=`"$fin`"/>"
```

It becomes true or false

Any idea to get my right result which should be 1 or 0?

As well another thing, my if is positioned at the beginning of my loop and he answer me with 1 or 0

```
$boucle = foreach ($list in $liste)

{
$fin = $list.UF6E8_CANAL -match "ML"
if ($list.UF6E8_CANAL -match "ML"){1}
else {0}

write-output "       <Index Nom=`"ALERTE_MAIL`" Valeur=`"$fin`"/>"
}
```

And so when I introduce it in the loop it answers me with the right answer (0 or 1)
But when I call the variable $fin it becomes true or false (I want it to be 1 or 0)

And also I would like to hide the result of the first call

Any idea?

Comment: you are not assigning the output of the `if` to anything ... it just goes to the screen if you want `$fin` to be `0/1` instead of `False/True` you need to assign it as such. PoSh will coerce `$False` to `0` and `$True` to `1`, so you can just use `[int]$Fin` to get that boolean converted to an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$fin` is of type boolean, so if you put it in a string, it's being implicitly converted to a string 'True' or 'False'. You could do `[int]$fin = $list.UF6E8_CANAL -match "ML"`, then when used in a string it will be converted to 0 or 1. It'll also work in conditional statements as value 0 will be converted back to boolean false and any other value to true.

Comment: perfect thank you I knew i've made somthing wrong
so now the right result gets in the line of my write-output but at the beginning of the loop i still got the resukt of the if statement appearing. Is there a way to make the if statement silentely continues. So my result would only appear in my write-output?

Comment: @HadrienBeaujean That if statement doesn't do anything except for outputting 0 or 1. If you don't need that, just remove it.

Comment: here is the example
1

       <Index Nom="ALERTE_MAIL" Valeur="1"/>
   <Document>

Comment: I'm not sure i f| out-null would be possible to use in this case